# Can I make an onActionExecuting call a method in a baseController with WebAPI?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Here's a filter that I have:

```
public class ABCFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            set();
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

Here's my base controller that controllers inherit from:

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public int abcd { get; private set; }

    public void set()
    {
        abcd = 123;
    }
```

I would like to call the function set() that's in the base controller. Is that possible and how could I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
public class ABCFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            (actionContext.ControllerContext.Controller as BaseController).set(); //Retrieve the current controller from the context.
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

But it's not recommended because action filters are designed to deal with cross-cutting concerns: [Cross cutting concern example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700540/cross-cutting-concern-example)

Using it like this **couples** the filter with specific controllers and cannot be reused for other controllers that are not derived from your `BaseController`

With your code, I think you can just implement the initialization logic inside `BaseController` constructor.

```
public class BaseController : ApiController
{
    public int abcd { get; private set; }
    public BaseController()
    {
        set();
    }
    public void set()
    {
        abcd = 123;
    }
```

Comment: I would like to implement in the base constructor but the code needs access to the HttpActionContext and from what I understand (might be wrong) it's not available in the base constructor.

Comment: @Alan: If that's the case, it's fine to define a filter used `only for BaseController`, but I don't really understand why you need this filter because you can access these context information in your action method.

Comment: Just wanting to keep the method looking clean.  Actually based on what you said I already have an auth filter and I put a call to set() in there.  Thanks for ur help.