# what "concern metrics" means in Software Engineering

Tags: reflection

Recently, I was reading a paper whose name is "On the Effectiveness of Concern Metrics to Detect Code Smells: An Empirical Study".

I come from a non-English speaking country, and I can not quite understand what Concern Metrics means in the field of software engineering.

It is not referring to the relationship between objects?

I have some understanding of java and c #, some people may be able to use java to give me an example.

Thanks.

Comment: This question may be more appropriate in [Software Engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @FredrikLundvall when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Ok, thanks! If OP should want to post a question on another site, should they delete the one here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like it is said in the paper's abstract: "While traditional metrics quantify properties of software modules, concern metrics quantify concern properties, such as scattering and tangling." Are you familiar to the cross-cutting concern concept? This question provides examples of concerns: [Cross cutting concern example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23700540/cross-cutting-concern-example) Try to read papers on [aspect-oriented programming (AOP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) to grasp more concepts in order to understand better the relationship between concerns and code. The metrics are attempts to quantify, for instance, the amount of scatterness of a concern (e.g. login) over the source code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Now I know that I have been following the concept of writing my java code, for example, in the realization of separation of concerns, but do not know it is called concern.

Comment: @Jiabin if this is the answer you were expecting, please mark it as answered. if you need further clarification, please let me know how I can help you.